# vuejs search filter with 2 v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the following filter computed

```js
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
        return {
           columns:{},
           search:"",
           trovato:{},
        };
        },
        
        
        computed: {

       
           searchit() {

              const sear =this.search.toLowerCase().trim();
              if(!sear) return this.columns;
              Array.from(this.columns).forEach(element => {
                 element.filter((item) => {
    
 
                    if(item.toLowerCase().includes(sear)){
                     
                       this.trovato = item;
                       console.log(this.trovato);
                       return this.trovato;
                    }
                 
                })
             })
           }
    }
</script>
```

it works in a good way, the console.log(this.trovato) print the correct column that matches the name i searched.

the problem is i'm not able to print it in a v-list, in the beginning it displays all the values of the var columns{}, but after i type something it doesn't display anything, it's all blank. this is the code i'm using:

```js
<v-list-item>
   <v-text-field append-icon="search" v-model="search" label="Cerca" ></v-text-field>
</v-list-item>
<v-list v-for="(item,index) in searchit" :key="index">
     <v-list-item v-for="ved in item" :key="ved.id">
         <v-list-item-content>
                                    
               <v-list-item-title >{{ved}}</v-list-item-title>
                                   
                                   
         </v-list-item-content>
     </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array and doesn't mutate the original array. (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

So here, you filter them but doesn't assign the new filtered array to anything, so it goes into the void.

Plus, it really a bad practise to mutate a component `data` from a computed. You're suppose to return a new object / array, derived from that data.

```js
searchit() {
  const sear =this.search.toLowerCase().trim();

  if(!sear) { return this.columns; }

  const newColumns = this.columns.map(col => {
     return col.filter((item) => {
        if(item.toLowerCase().includes(sear)){
           this.trovato = item; // If possible, avoid setting data from a computed
           return this.trovato;
        }
      })
  })
  return newColumns;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works now. And thank you for your suggestion, i removed the "if" and put directly: "return item.toLowerCase().includes(sear)", so i don't have to set the data from a computed.